# Mavensmate New Project Creation Not Working - MavensMate-app

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

Has anyone encountered issues creating a new project through the MavensMate-app? It just keeps on loading. It just displays the message "Creating new MavensMate Project" for hours together. Please provide solution if anyone has figured it out.

Thanks,
Sriram.

Answer (score 3):

As per the GitHub site https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-app, they have packaged the local MavensMate server into a nifty, cross-platform application called MavensMate-app. Why did they do it? Quite simply, to make it easier to install and run MavensMate. All MavensMate plugins (Sublime Text, Atom, etc.) now require MavensMate-app to be installed and running in order to function properly.

So download and install the app from here https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate-app/releases according to your OS version.

Now got to  (SublimeText) MaventsMate > Settings > User Pluggin seeting and update `mm_mavensmate_app_location` to the MavensMate-app installation path.

In MavensMate-app global settings(can be found in the MavensMate-app menu) change the `mm_workspace` to your mavensmate workspace folder.

Now you can user your MavensMate from SublimeText. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated it already but of no use, it still takes forever to create the project.

Answer (score 2):

After the recent updates to the MavensMate-app, Mavensmate.exe needs to be running while trying to update a project, otherwise it will throw the error:

> "Could not contact local MavensMate server, please ensure MavensMate-app is installed and running."

Go to your `C:\Program file.. \ mavensmate \ mavensmate.exe` and run `mavensmate.exe`.

I use the [v6](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-app/releases/tag/v0.0.6) and it works well.

Comment: I am already using v0.0.6, problem is it takes forever to create a new project. I have waited nearly for 2 hours and still project was not created in my local workspace. I have updated the workspace location and logs location and also mm_mavensmate_app_location in SublimeText.

Comment: Did you check mavensmate global settings? The workspace, etc.. need to be updated in global settings. They are on mavensmate-->settings, Or Are you behind a proxy?
Make sure that you have just the basic components in package.xml? I prefer to first try in my dev Org which has a very few components. A large project takes a while for me.

Comment: I have already taken care of the pre-requisites like the global settings and so forth. No proxy and also trying to import only Apex classes and Pages from my Sandbox env - its not so huge. Anyways thanks for the advise, I will try to remove everything and re-install.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have fixed this, but I got similar problem which got solved really easy.

The thing is that the default path given in the package user control is

```
"mm_workspace" : "/Users/WTF/Desktop/Application/",
```

After I just added the drive volume (C:) before the line, it "magically" worked : ))

```
"mm_workspace" : "C:/Users/WTF/Desktop/Application/",
```

I hope this ridiculous fix will solve the issue :)